# Passing Infopath form field value to SQL query

Tags: sql, infopath

I want to use Infopath 2010 form field values in SQL statement when defining  data connection.

The problem is that I was unable to find out the appropriate syntax.

So, if I have a single textbox called Name_tb, how could I use his value? in a simple query like:

SELECT [textbox]

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember it off the top of my head but it's a DOM like syntax to access the fields at runtime.